# Remove multiple values from [list] dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.x

I am trying to remove all values `'x'` from a large dictionary and NOT delete any keys, but when I run the code there are still `'x'` values remaining.

Here is an excerpt of my dictionary:

```
myDict = {0: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 1: ['id1', 'id2', 'x', 'x'], 2: ['id1', 'x', 'x', 'x']}
```

My code thus far:

```
for k, v in myDict.iteritems():
if v == 'x':
    myDict.remove('x')
print myDict
```

What I am aiming for:

```
myDict = {0: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 1: ['id1', 'id2'], 2: ['id1']}
```

How should I remove the `'x'` values in the lists, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension within a dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
myDict = {k:[el for el in v if el != 'x'] for k, v in myDict.items()}
print(myDict)
```

**Output**

```
{0: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 1: ['id1', 'id2'], 2: ['id1']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
for key in myDict:
    while 'x' in myDict[key]:
        myDict[key].remove('x')
```

Yours doesn't work because you are using `.remove()` on the dictionary, not on the lists inside.  You need that `while` loop that I used because `.remove()` removes only the first one.  Therefore, I just keep removing the first one until there are none left.

Comment: Note that `'x' in myDict[key]` and `myDict[key].remove('x')` are both O(n) operations. Since OP said his dictionary is large, this solution might be too slow with complexity O(nmk).

Comment: Those are `O(n)` operations, but the OP said the *dictionary* was large, not necessarily the lists used as values.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple flaws in your code:

1. You are calling `remove` on the dictionary itself, not on the lists it has as values.
2. Dictionaries don't have an attribute `remove`.
3. `v == 'x'` checks whether any value is equal to `'x'`, which is never `True` because all your values are lists, which may or may not *contain* `'x'`.
4. Even calling `remove` on the lists itself would only remove the first occurrence of `'x'`.

The easiest way is to build a new dictionary:

```
>>> {k:[x for x in v if x!='x'] for k,v in myDict.iteritems()}
{0: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 1: ['id1', 'id2'], 2: ['id1']}
```

You could also modify your dictionary in place and just set the values to new lists:

```
>>> for k,v in myDict.iteritems():
...     myDict[k] = [x for x in v if x!='x']
... 
>>> myDict
{0: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 1: ['id1', 'id2'], 2: ['id1']}
```

If you prefer the functional approach, everywhere I use a list comprehension you could use `filter` instead. Demo:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x!='x', ['id1', 'x', 'x', 'x'])
['id1']
```

Answer (score 1):

For python2 just do:

```
for k, v in myDict.iteritems():
    if v == 'x':
        myDict[k].remove('x')
```

The issue was you called `remove` method from dict instead of dict element(myDict[k]]

I think you're on Python2 since you use iteritems(). For python 3 you can do it with dict comprehensions whose not available for 2nd version.